Auto populating X and Y in Esri Enterprise
I have created a point layer in ArcGIS Enterprise with the intention of collecting Latitude and Longitude data of points to be collected. Is there a way to set the layer so that it populates the X and Y fields automatically when the points are collected? The layer is being created within Enterprise.

I don't think this is possible.  You can use the 'Add Geometry Attributes' tool to automatically populate X and Y attributes with coordinates.  But that only works for the time at which you run the tool, not when new features are created (or moved!).  Depending on the context, though, you can still access the X and Y coordinates without having them explicitly within separate attributes (fields).  What is the end use-case for this?...

Eg, for just viewing the X and Y coordinates, you can use the 'Attributes' pane to see the attributes of a selected feature.  You can switch the 'Attributes' pane to the 'Geometry' view to view the coordinates instead of the attributes.  If you need access to the coordinates in other situations (eg, in a Python script, or model) you can use the SHAPE@XY (or SHAPE@X and SHAPE@Y) of a feature's geometry object, or you can use these tokens in cursor attribute lists.

Note that auto-populating X/Y coordinates as attributes would be potentially dangerous (as is manually populating them) if they are not also automatically updated whenever the geometry updated.  Otherwise they could end up with the wrong coordinates that are not longer in sync with the true geometry.
